# VB to C# substitution

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a trivial problem, but I can't solve it somehow. 
I have an example of code in VB

```
If(grid(x,y).Used = True)Then
   grid(x,y).Used = False
   ....
End If
```

which look in c# like this

```
 if(grid[x,y]."" == false)
    {
       grid[x,y]."" = true;
    }
```

I can't find a substitute for "Used".
I know that it's kinda stupid, but I just can't figure it out.
Thanks for any advice or help.

Comment: what is the data type of `grid` exactly?

Comment: What is the type of grid? Given your exaple, I'd expect that the type of object should have a property called 'Used' which is a boolean.

Comment: Well, it's just a Panel[,], two-dimensional array, I just wanted to paint a grid in Windows Form (which is working) and I want to change color of one cell by pressing button. I'm trying to program a Connect 4

Comment: What is `(grid[x,y].""`?

Comment: not an answer, but it would be the next issue you'd run in to. in C# the comparator is == and not =. but like Jay said, it should have a property that is a bool. You could also just say !grid[x,y] instead of checking If(false)

Comment: `Used` isn't a property on a WinForms `Panel`, nor a keyword in VB.NET as far as I know. Inspect the original code and see where the `Used` property comes from.

Comment: C#'s equivalent of `=` (for equality checks) is not `=` but `==`.

Comment: The C# code is nonsense.  Could happen if you used a decompiler to recover source code from an obfuscated assembly.  A standard trick that an obfuscator uses is to replace characters in an identifier with unprintable control codes or characters that guarantee a compile error.  Like double-quotes.  Obfuscated assemblies advertise "don't steal this code".  And enforce it.

Comment: Your edit is a completely different problem. Why did you change `=` to `==`? You should mark @cmos as correct and then create a new question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decompile protected C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567547/decompile-protected-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to access your array correctly. Like this:

```
if(grid[x][y].Used == false)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Please also note that the correct syntax in C# to check for equality requires you to use the '==' operator (equality operator).

Comment: The equality check is redundant alltogether; your code is asking the overcmplicated "*if its true that true equals true*" when you could simply ask "*if its true*"

Comment: Of course you are right, but I wanted to let op see, that to check for equality you have to use another operator. In case of checking a bool value of course, this is redundant.